# Ansible, jenkins_script module and problem with args

Tags: jenkins, groovy, ansible

I am using this module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/jenkins_script_module.html

And I want to pass arguments(dictionary: jenkins_username_password_credentials) to my Groovy script that can change credentials on Jenkins:

```
#! / usr / bin / env groovy

import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsScope
import hudson.util.Secret
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl

instance = Jenkins.instance
domain = Domain.global ()
store = instance.getExtensionList (
  "com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider") [0] .getStore ()

{% for credential in jenkins_username_password_credentials%}
usernameAndPassword = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl (
  CredentialsScope.GLOBAL,
  "{{credential ['name']}}",
  "{{credential ['description']}}",
  "{{credential ['username']}}",
  "{{credential ['password']}}"
)

store.addCredentials (domain, usernameAndPassword)
{% endfor%}
```

I do it through the given code:

```
- name: Upload Nexus credentials
  jenkins_script:
    url: "{{jenkins_url}}"
    script: '{{lookup ("template", "templates / jenkins_groovy / credentials / secret_password.groovy")}}'
    args:
            jenkins_username_password_credentials:
                    - name: Nexus
                      description: Credentials for Nexus Server
                      username: Nexus
                      password: 25447
    user: '{{jenkins_username}}'
    password: '{{jenkins_password}}'
    validate_certs: false
    timeout: "120"
```

But I have an error that my variable `jenkins_username_password_credentials` is undefined until I add it to the defaults file in my role.

```
fatal: [jenkins_linux]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'jenkins_username_password_credentials' is undefined \ n \ nThe error appears to be in' / home / tbaburin / Ansible / roles / jenkins / tasks / main.yml ': line 3, column 3, but may \ nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem. \ n \ nThe offending line appears to be: \ n \ n \ n- name: Upload Nexus credentials \ n ^ here \ n "}
```

My questions are:

- Can I declare a dictionary directly in the "args" field of the jenkins_script module like in the example? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/jenkins_script_module.html
- If I can't, how can I change the dictionary in the "args" field so that the modified dictionary with the data I need is loaded into the script?

I just don't want to always go into the default file and change the dictionary data there to load different credentials and I want just to pass some j2 variables into args just to loop this, if I want to upload a lot of credentials.

Comment: From my understanding, you're confusing `string.Template` described in the module documentation and jinja2 template you are trying to use. In your case, the variable you want to loop on in your template must be defined (i.e. declared in a var section or in your inventory). Declared in `args` as you did, it will not be. If I were you, I would still pass the arg to the groovy script assign the value of the arg with [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) to a groovy var and loop directly on that variable right in the groovy script.

Comment: I just don't know how to do it correctly with string.Template in Ansible, can you please give me an example?

Comment: You mean one that would not be already in the module documentation page nor in the `string.Template` documentation page I already linked above? => `whatever_groovy_var = "$name_of_your_dict_entry_in_args_formated_as_what_you_need"`. Hint. you can probably pass your data as a json string (`to_json` filter) and decode the json string inside groovy to get a clean object/list you can easilly manipulate.